# How to select First String in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

what i  Need :

- i Need only First Name from the String.

  ```
     Like String : Bodo Jorg Udo .. ( i have .. notation if string of length is more then 20).
  ```

  here is source code

  ```
          {%if item.metadata.name |length < 20 %}
          {{item.metadata.name}}
          {%else%}{{WordLimit(item.metadata.name,10,10)}} ..
             {%endif%}
  ```

  output should be like

  ```
   Bodo
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Split filter of Twig to match the whitespace character. It'll return an array containing your splitted string.

```
New in version 1.10.3: The split filter was added in Twig 1.10.3.
The split filter splits a string by the given delimiter and returns a list of strings:

{% set foo = "one,two,three"|split(',') %}
{# foo contains ['one', 'two', 'three'] #}
```

In your case you'll want to replace the comma by a whitespace `| split(' ')`

More info in the [Split page](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html) of Twig documentation.

Comment: after split add First filter, it will get you your first name. `{% set yourVariable = yourString|split(' ')|First() %}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the  truncate filter from the Text Extension.
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/text.html

You can configure it by adding a service definition like this:

```
services:
 twig.extension.text:
     class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
     tags:
         - { name: twig.extension }
```

Then you can apply the filter:

```
 {{ item.metadata.name|truncate(10) }}
```

The filter have some arguments, and the one that matters for you is the separator value(by default its "..." which is the value you want if the string have more that 10 characters)